# Warning message when including numpy/arryobject.h

Tags: c++, numpy

I'm trying to include NumPy objects from C++ code.
I started this from today, and as a first sample program, I made the following stub code.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <iostream>

static PyObject* SpamError;

int main(void) {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
  return (0);
}
```

I used the following command for building. I did building on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
g++ -o out test.cc -I/usr/include/python2.7  -lpython2.7
```

But if I use the above build command, then the following error message appears.

```
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
```

I do not clearly understand the meaning of this, and I would like to know how to avoid this issue. Could anyone give some advice on this?

Comment: The warning is telling you the current NumPy version is old please use an up to date version of this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either upgrade to the latest library as pointed by the error or add #define as below to your code

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <iostream>

static PyObject* SpamError;

int main(void) {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1250). If you read the thread there, it seems like you could 1. upgrade your `numpy` version, 2. ignore it until you do, or 3. for the time being, use the `#define` mentioned in the warning message:

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API 

#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Of course, upgrading to a version where this warning does not occur is the best alternative (but not always possible).